# How to verify a Firebase ID token using jose in node?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, jose

I'm trying to verify a JWT (session cookie) following the [instructions here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) guided by [this sample implementation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76979358/2146894) using the [jose package](https://github.com/panva/jose) (although I'm open to other node packages).

### Why?

I'm aware that I can use Firebase's [`verifySessionCookie`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth#baseauthverifysessioncookie) to do this. In fact, that's what I'm doing currently and it works..

```
export async function getDecodedSessionCookie() {
  // Get the sessionCookie
  const sessionCookie = cookies().get("sessionCookie")
  if (sessionCookie === undefined) return null

  // Verify the cookie but don't check if the cookie has
  // been revoked not sure if this is a security risk,
  // but it appears to add significant latency
  return (
    adminAuth
      .verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie.value, false)

      // If the cookie is verified, return the decodedClaims
      .then((decodedClaims) => {
        return decodedClaims
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log("error", e))
  )
}
```

BUT it's annoyingly slow and it can't be executed in Vercel's Edge runtime.

### What I've Tried

This topic is a little above my head, but here's what I've tried..

```
export async function getDecodedSessionCookie2() {
  // Return null if the cookie doesn't exist or it's invalid
  const sessionCookie = cookies().get("sessionCookie")
  if (sessionCookie === undefined) return null

  // Decode the header (this works)
  const header = jose.decodeProtectedHeader(sessionCookie.value)
  console.log("header", header)

  // Decode the cookie (this works)
  const sessionCookieDecoded = jose.decodeJwt(sessionCookie.value)
  console.log("sessionCookieDecoded", sessionCookieDecoded)

  // Create the remote key set 
  // (This errors with message: JSON Web Key Set malformed)
  const JWKS = jose.createRemoteJWKSet(
    new URL(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    )
  )
  const keyset = await JWKS()
  console.log("keyset", keyset)

  // Never made it here
  const audience = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
  const issuer = `https://securetoken.google.com/${audience}`

  // Never made it here
  const { payload, protectedHeader } = await jose.jwtVerify(
    sessionCookie.value,
    JWKS,
    {
      issuer,
      audience,
    }
  )
  console.log("protectedHeader", protectedHeader)
  console.log("payload", payload)

  // Not sure if this is needed?
  // const x509 = certificates["7cf7f8727091e4c77aa995db60743b7dd2bb70b5"]
  // const ecPublicKey = await jose.importX509(x509, algorithm)

  return sessionCookieDecoded
}
```

Mostly this is just a lot of tinkering and exploration, but I *think* I need to create a remote keyset with `createRemoteJWKSet` and this is the step I can't get past.

### Additional notes

1. Firebase tokens should have a `kid` in the header.

   1. In production, I see `kid: lk02Aw`. As far as I can tell, **this does not correspond to any of the [public keys](https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com)**
   2. In local development with the Auth Emulator, `kid` does not exist.
2. Do the public certificates change frequently?

### Updates

- I was able to get past the error above with some [guidance from the author of the jose package](https://github.com/panva/jose/discussions/626#discussioncomment-8119194). Will update with complete details if/when I finish implementing token verification.
- I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73384809/2146894) by John Hanley noting that Google's public keys rotate every 12 hours.

Comment: If you inspect the JWT at https://jwt.io/ you can see that it's not signed (see `none` for `alg`), or encrypted. Therefore there is no verifying it bcs there's no signature to examine.

Comment: Alg is `RS256`. It should be verifiable according to Firebase docs. Also, hello from a fellow New Orleanian.

Comment: Cool! Do you have the public key? If so, here's how you verify using Node's crypto library. I'm sure it could be done in the browser w the subtle.crypto API. https://gist.github.com/ronnieroyston/b15bc38341b70e5e63da6327375555d0

Comment: According to the docs, public keys are listed here: https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com  ...but I'd rather not use Node's crypto library as it's been discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with native Node.

#### Get Token

I was able to get my token from the browser by opening Developer Tools (cntrl+shift+i) and entering:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously
```

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {console.log(idToken)}).
```

#### Get Public Key(s)

Google's Public Keys are published at https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com passed as a string `publicKeyGoogle` to script below.

#### Run Node Script

```
const {createVerify, createPublicKey} = await import('node:crypto');
(async function () {
  console.log(await validateJWS(myJWT));
})();
async function validateJWS(jwt){
  try {
    let jwtParts = jwt.split('.');
    let jwtHeader = jwtParts[0];
    let jwtPayload = jwtParts[1];
    let jwtSignature = jwtParts[2];
    let valid = false;
    let header = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(jwtHeader, 'base64url').toString('utf-8'));
    let alg = header.alg;
    if(alg === "RS256"){ // MUST verify alg is not set to none
      let verify = createVerify('SHA256');
      verify.write(jwtHeader + '.' + jwtPayload);
      verify.end();
      let googleKey = publicKeyGoogle[Object.keys(publicKeyGoogle)[0]];
      valid = verify.verify(googleKey, jwtSignature, 'base64url');
      if(valid){
        return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(jwtPayload, 'base64url').toString('utf-8'));
      } else {
        throw (error)
      }
    } else {
      throw (error)     
    }
  } catch (e) {
    //console.log (e);
    return "\x1b[31mInvalid Token!\x1b[37m";
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasnt able to get this to work. I kep getting `valid` as false. 
Additionally, what is the purpose of `createPublicKey` here?

Comment: createPublicKey has no effect as it's not used. It's in there from a paste.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work this out with a lot of [help](https://github.com/panva/jose/discussions/626) from @panva (the author of [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose)). So, shout out to him!

---

### Code

```js
import * as jose from "jose"
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

let publicKeys

async function sessionPublicKeyResolver(protectedHeader) {
  const { kid, alg } = protectedHeader
  if (!publicKeys || !(kid in publicKeys)) {
    publicKeys = await fetch(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/publicKeys"
    ).then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    })
  }

  // key object was not cached yet
  if (typeof publicKeys[kid] === "string") {
    publicKeys[kid] = await jose.importX509(publicKeys[kid], alg)
  }

  return publicKeys[kid]
}

export async function getDecodedSessionCookie() {
  // Get the decoded session cookie (JWT)

  // Return null if the cookie doesn't exist or it's invalid
  const sessionCookie = cookies().get("sessionCookie")
  if (sessionCookie === undefined) return null

  let payload
  let header

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    // ONLY IN DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENTS
    const verifiedToken = jose.UnsecuredJWT.decode(sessionCookie.value)
    payload = verifiedToken.payload
    header = verifiedToken.header
  } else {
    const audience = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
    const issuer = `https://session.firebase.google.com/${audience}`

    // https://github.com/panva/jose/discussions/448
    const verifiedToken = await jose.jwtVerify(
      sessionCookie.value,
      sessionPublicKeyResolver,
      {
        issuer,
        audience,
      }
    )
    payload = verifiedToken.payload
    header = verifiedToken.protectedHeader
  }

  // Complete the rest of the checks
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#verify_session_cookies_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

  // sub (subject) Must be a non-empty string and must be the uid of the user or device.
  if (payload.sub !== payload.user_id) {
    throw new Error("JWT sub does not equal user_id")
  }

  // exp (expiration) must be in the future. The time is measured in seconds since the UNIX epoch.
  // The expiration is set based on the custom duration provided when the cookie is created.
  if (payload.exp <= Date.now() / 1000) {
    throw new Error("JWT exp must be in the future")
  }

  // iat (Issued-at time) Must be in the past.
  // The time is measured in seconds since the UNIX epoch.
  if (payload.iat >= Date.now() / 1000) {
    throw new Error("JWT iat must be in the past")
  }

  // auth_time (Authentication time) Must be in the past. The time when the user authenticated.
  // This matches the auth_time of the ID token used to create the session cookie.
  if (payload.auth_time >= Date.now() / 1000) {
    throw new Error("JWT auth_time must be in the past")
  }

  return payload
}
```

Comment: Node is capable w/o a package.

Comment: @RonnieRoyston I see, that's really cool and thank you for taking the time to post an answer. The downside is that `node:crypto` can't be loaded on Next.js's Edge runtime, last time I checked.

Comment: Web Crypto (Subtle) API is supported, which can do it too in case you needed it. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/edge#crypto-apis

Answer (score 0):

I used this code found here: https://zuplo.com/blog/2023/04/05/using-jose-to-validate-a-firebase-jwt,

```
let publicKeys: any;
 
const getPublicKeys = async () => {
  if (publicKeys) {
    return publicKeys;
  }
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com`,
  );
  publicKeys = await res.json();
  return publicKeys;
};
 
// This goes
// inside your auth function or middleware
 
const authHeader = request.headers.get("authorization");
const token = authHeader.substring("bearer ".length);
 
const firebaseProjectId = "your-project-id";
 
const verifyFirebaseJwt = async (firebaseJwt) => {
  const publicKeys = await getPublicKeys();
  const decodedToken = await jwtVerify(
    firebaseJwt,
    async (header, _alg) => {
      const x509Cert = publicKeys[header.kid];
      const publicKey = await importX509(x509Cert, "RS256");
      return publicKey;
    },
    {
      issuer: `https://securetoken.google.com/${firebaseProjectId}`,
      audience: firebaseProjectId,
      algorithms: ["RS256"],
    },
  );
  return decodedToken.payload;
};
```

It worth nothing that tokens in the emulator aren't signed so you just need to use the decodeJwt to get basic data, somthing like this:

```
const verifyFirebaseJwt = async (firebaseJwt) => {
  const publicKeys = await getPublicKeys();
  if (__DEV__) {
    const res = jose.decodeJwt(firebaseJwt);
    return res;
  }

  const decodedToken = await jose.jwtVerify(
    firebaseJwt,
    async (header) => {
      const x509Cert = publicKeys[header.kid || ""];
      const publicKey = await jose.importX509(x509Cert, "RS256");
      return publicKey;
    },
    {
      issuer: `https://securetoken.google.com/${firebaseProjectId}`,
      audience: firebaseProjectId,
      algorithms: ["RS256"],
    }
  );
  return decodedToken.payload;
};
```